# What property of Typescript's number or Math.ceil() causes this arithmetic error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, math

I'm trying to create a function to generate a unique number every time using Typescript. The arithmetic is often incorrect for some reason. I've expanded the logic below and suspect that it has something to do with Typescript/Javascript's number type or Math.ceil(). I'd be grateful if someone could educate me.

```typescript
function nonce(){
    const millidate = (new Date()).getTime();
    const factor:number = 10000;
    const codeTime:number = +millidate*factor;
    const codeEnd:number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*factor);
    const codeMult:number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
    const codeBody:number = codeTime+codeEnd;
    const code:number =  codeBody*codeMult;
    console.log("Breakdown of " + code + ": ", codeTime, codeEnd, codeBody, codeMult);
    return code;
};


nonce();
```

Image of some tests in Playground

[image: Image of some tests in Playground]

I was using Typescript's Playground to test this, but its performance seems to be the same across different environments.

Comment: You are of course aware that JS integers only go up `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, right?

Comment: `(Date.now() * 10000) > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: (also note that unless you're doing this purely to "see if you can", you almost certainly want a uuid library instead, like https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Comment: [Please consider replacing or supplementing images of text with a plaintext version.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, your numbers are way over the system limit. `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` on my 64-bit system:

```
9007199254740991 <- MSI
163469121917820770 <- your number
```

Dial it down, or make strings.

Answer (score 0):

To work with large numbers (more than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`), you need to use [BigInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Without BigInt:

```
9007199254740991 + 1 = 9007199254740992 // Right
9007199254740991 + 2 = 9007199254740992 // Wrong
9007199254740991 + 3 = 9007199254740994 // Right
```

Using BigInt:

```
9007199254740991n + 1n = 9007199254740992n //Right
9007199254740991n + 2n = 9007199254740993n //Right
9007199254740991n + 3n = 9007199254740994n //Right
```